# Outlook pops a windows security window asking for credentials when using Redemption dll

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-redemption

I have a console program which uses Redemption dll to connect to outlook 2016 and send some emails between 2 users.

The purpose of this program is to test the exchange/outlook. So, in the program, we send emails, make meeting schedule, ...., and then keep looping and do the same thing again and again.

We found a weird issue when running this program. Sometimes, the program will popup a window and ask for credentials. The user's credential is hardcoded, and obviously works fine. As shown in the screen shot, the program runs about 476 times ok, the popup shows up at the 477th loop. The popup is kind of random, not always shows up at the 477th loop. On some machines, the popup shows up at the 5th loop.

If we kill the console program using Taskmgr, then restart the console program, it keeps running and does not popup this credential window.

Anyone see this before? Especially using Redemption? How to fix this?

Thanks

[image]

- here is some code. I think the popup happens because of

  ```
   RedemptionSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox(Mailbox, Mailbox, Password);
  ```

**but, weird thing is why it is ok for the first 466 times? is it possible to disable this popup even if we have to let the logon fail.**

```
internal bool Login()
{
    bool result = false;

    if (RedemptionSession == null)
    {
        if (InitializeRedemption() == false)
        {
            string error = "Unable to initialize Redemption";
            Log.Error(error);
            TestResult = new TestResult(TestStatuses.Failure, error);
            return result;
        }
    }
... check parameters....

    LoginBegin = DateTime.Now;

    try
    {
        RedemptionSession.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox(Mailbox, Mailbox, Password);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex);
        TestResult = new TestResult(TestStatuses.Failure, ex.Message);
        return result;
    }

    LoginEnd = DateTime.Now;
    result = RedemptionSession.LoggedOn;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did the "tool" has some kind of logging to check whats happening at this action? Did the login failed so that it caused an error, did an timeout happen? Additional it could be the trotteling policy from Exchange which blocks the tool.

Comment: Please post the relevant snippets of your code.

Comment: Hi， Dmitry, I added the code, if you need more code, please let me know. or, can we talk offline or by email?

Comment: What is the rest of your code that actually accesses Exchange objects? Or do you just call the code above in a loop?

Comment: I get this behavior when for password is wrong. I guess at some point, if the autodiscover protocol fail, then you have to supply username/password again for a retry.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the tool did (at which time and more infos from the Exchange environment) it isn´t that easy to guess what might be the reason. The closest I could currently think of is the [ThrottlingPolicy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863577(v=exchg.150).aspx) as your tool looks like is doing much more "traffic" then a normal user. Depending on the actions the tool performs and the policy it *MIGHT* be that the policy kicks in and this is seen as an "password prompt".

So to check that you can do some further log debugging on Exchange or if the Exchange administrator agreed to that build a [new ThrottlingPolicy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351045(v=exchg.160).aspx) for the specified taskuser which is used in your tool and give them [higher values](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298094(v=exchg.160).aspx).

P.S.
Keep noted that IF the throttling policy is causing the issue you might wish to re-think your code as its not possible to change the throttling policys when using Exchange Online as written [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2011/06/23/exchange-online-throttling-and-limits-faq/). An idea might be (just for debugging) add 30sec hold between the actions to see if that solved the issue.